# Why responseEvent.getResponse() is null?

Tags: java, snmp

i want to learn and test SNMP. in my application i want to test snmp from a windows 10 pc to an ubuntu pc for get some details.
There is an error when i run application:

> responseEvent.getResponse() is null

.
Please help.

here is my code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        OctetString community1 = new OctetString("public");
        Address targetaddress = new UdpAddress("127.0.0.1/161");
        TransportMapping transportMapping = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        transportMapping.listen();
        CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
        comtarget.setCommunity(community1);
        comtarget.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version1);
        comtarget.setAddress(targetaddress);
        comtarget.setRetries(2);
        comtarget.setTimeout(10000);
        PDU pdu = new PDU();
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0")));
        pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transportMapping);

        ResponseEvent responseEvent = snmp.get(pdu, comtarget);
        String str = "";
        if (responseEvent != null && responseEvent.getResponse().getErrorStatusText().equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
            PDU pduresponse = responseEvent.getResponse();
            str = pduresponse.getVariableBindings().firstElement().toString();
            if (str.contains("=")) {
                int len = str.indexOf("=");
                str = str.substring(len + 1, str.length());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("responseEvent or responseEvent.getResponse() == null.  Feeling like a TimeOut occured ");
        }
        snmp.close();
        System.out.println(str);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the method to see if it says anything?

Comment: No, Which documentation do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

> ...in my application i want to test snmp from a windows 10 pc to an
>   ubuntu pc for get some details...

You'll probably want to use a different `targetaddress`, because with "127.0.0.1/161" you'll be sending the request to localhost. I'm guessing 127.0.0.1 should be replaced with the IP-address of the PC you're querying...

That other PC must of course have some sort of SNMP-daemon running on port 161/UDP, which is configured to respond to the request.

Comment: That other PC IP is 10.1.74.3
 when i replace this ip with 127.0.0.1 responseEvent.getResponse() is null.

Comment: So, is there a SNMP-daemon running on that other PC? And, if yes, is that SNMP-daemon configured to respond to SNMP-requests with community 'public' from the IP from which you are running your code?

Comment: Sorry, How can i check that SNMP_deamon is running or not?

Comment: I use service snmpd start to start snmp service.

Comment: That's a start, but check how snmpd is configured using the [manpage](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html) and [examples](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.examples.html).

Comment: Why i don't have #agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161 line in snmpd.conf file?

Comment: What you'll need is something like `agentadress 1.2.3.4:161` where 1.2.3.4 is the IP of the system snmp is running on. You'll probably will need to define the 'public'-community and even which from which IP requests with that community are allowed to come from.